# Using SQL BETWEEN

Tags: sql

Please help me fix this error.

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM activity_log_admins
WHERE query_date BETWEEN 4th-June-2022 AND 10th-June-2022
```

But am receiving this error.

> #1054 - Unknown column '4th' in 'where clause'

Comment: You need to put values in single quotes: `... BETWEEN '4th-June-2022' AND '10th-June-2022'` ... that is if this kind of date format is even accepted.

Comment: What is the data type of column `query_date` in database table `activity_log_admins`?

Comment: Refer to MySQL documentation for [date and time literals](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-literals.html).

Comment: Your issue isn't the BETWEEN keyword but "how to write a date literal"

Comment: OT watch out for timestamps and "between" - when this query works it will include June 10th 0:00, but not 0:01 or later. Probably use "query_date >= start AND query_date < end"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `query_date` is a type of datetime, Try

```sql
SELECT 
    * 
FROM activity_log_admins 
WHERE query_date BETWEEN '2202-06-04' AND '2202-06-10'
```